# jQuery form Ajax submit issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, preventdefault

I have a div (`#ajax-progress`) containing multiple forms. I'm trying to get the div contents reloading when any of the forms are submitted. If I do this:

```
    $("#ajax-progress form").click(function(event){
        alert('something');
```

and click anywhere in one of the forms, it alerts correctly (so the selector seems correct). But! If I change it to submit:

```
    $("#ajax-progress form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('something');
```

my jQuery seems to be ignored and the form submits normally. What am I missing?

Edit: I was thinking it might be something to do with this on some of my forms?

`<input id="file-upload" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit();" name="file">`

But I do need some of the forms submitting when a file is selected for upload. Could be a red herring anyway because other forms in the div that are just `textarea` and submit button exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you watching the inspector to see if an error is thrown when you click the submit button (right before the page refreshes)?

Comment: This is hard to debug without a complete [mcve]

Comment: Sorry - I've added some HTML that might be the problem. I can add more if needed.

Comment: @Kinglish that's a good idea but nothing is flashing up.